# Assigning var type like GURUBI

Tags: cplex, docplex

I was looking through the documentation of docplex to check if I could find a similar method to the one option used in GURUBI which assigns the var type of the decision variables after they are created.

For example, when creating a new set of continuous decision variables we can just:

`mdl.continuous_var_list(n_variables, lb, ub)`

Being `ub` and `lb` list with the values for the upper bound and lower bound. I was wondering if there is a way to instead of choosing the method `continuous_var_list`, use a more general one where the type of the variable is also a parameter.

I'm doing this because I have both integer and continuous variables and for the constraints creation it is just easier if they are a single vector.

I couldn't find this option either in `docplex.mp.dvar` module or `docplex.mp.model` module.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a list of variables with mixed types is not presently doable in Docplex. However, if you need to consider all your variables as a vector, there is an easy workaround, using `Model.iter_variables()`.
This iterator traverses all variables, in creation order, so building an ordered list of variables is as simple as

```
 all_vars = list(mymodel.iter_variables())
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: It does indeed! I was using `find_matching_vars('')` that returned a list, but this is more direct since I don't have to name all my variables. Thank you once again!